How do I get a reverted transaction id from an AAVE flashloan request?
How do i get a reverted transaction receipt id from an AAVE flashloan request on the mainnet?
The transaction fails and rollsback, but I don't see any tx receipt output for the failed transaction to follow up on.
As an example, in the hardhat typescript, I make a pretty standard call the requestFlashLoan function in the solidity smart contract:
async function requestFlashLoan(deployer : Signer) {
    // Instantiate FLA Contract 
    
    const contractFLASend = new ethers.Contract(
        FLA_CONTRACT_ADDRESS,
        abiFLASend,
        deployer
      );

    // Request Flashloan and Swap of Tokens  
    await contractFLASend.requestFlashLoan(TOKEN0_ADDRESS, TOKEN0_AMOUNT, SWAP_CONTRACT_ADDRESS, 
        TRANSACTION_DATA);

}

Then when the Solidity function gets called:
requestFlashLoan -- which is pretty boiler plate for AAVE and the payback fails because I'm short of money to payback the loan, the whole transaction accordingly rollsback--which it should do, but I'm unclear on how to get the transaction receipt in the typescript code from the rolled back transaction.

A reverted transactions will have a tranaction receipt similar to any transaction.

Reverted transaction receipt status is 0 instead of 1
No logs (events) are generated as everything is fully reverted

Hope this helps. Without more details in your question it is impossible to give a better answer.

I am going to update my original question with code--I realized after my I posted my original question that I was sparse on the details--sorry about that.

I've added some detail to my original question.
